# Summer time not persisted

Tags: xamarin.forms, akavache

If I put a summer time date into the cache then it comes out without the summer time applied.

e.g. 14:00+1 (15:00) comes back out of the cache as 14:00.

In non-summer time, there's no problem.

I've raised an [issue](https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache/issues/492) on GitHub, which has been unanswered in a week.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show a code sample?  Which timezone and locale settings are you using?

Comment: I received an answer. They said to use a `JsonSerializerSettings` override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with...

```
BlobCache.Secure.ForcedDateTimeKind = DateTimeKind.Local;
```

https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache/issues/492